# Favicon does not work under a specific server, but works for others

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, favicon

I have an issue which is one of those mysterious occurrences that seems to happen all too often in the IT world.

Naturally there must be a single easy solution for this, so I address the great SO:

**My** `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />` **does not appear when browsing our website from a specific server, but works for others.**

The server is using IIS 6 and the site is always browsed using SSL.

The server can serve the icon if you request it directly, but never appears otherwise.

Locally and all other test servers operate as expected, which differ with IIS 7 in some cases, while others do not differ at all.

We have tried everything we can think of, even checking the policies on the server in case they are forbidding `.ico`. I don't want to elaborate as to what we tried, as I also don't want to lead any possible answers.

The machine resides in the client's area, thus we have limited access and our test runs aren't as thorough as we may have wanted them to be.

tia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing browser cache.

Maybe seems a silly suggestion, but I had this problem.
Browsers like Chrome keeps Favicon cached... forever :)

Comment: tried an infinite amount of times, every cache possible, even tried a new client machine. all suggestions are good as long as they are valid, so thanks, keep them coming.

Comment: i have not resolved this, but i'll mark as correct since it will most probably be the case for someone else.